# AWS API Gateway - Send requests through corporate proxy

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

With AWS API Gateway, is there a way to send a request through a corporate proxy? Let's say that I have a service that will only accept traffic sourced from `http://proxy.my-proxy.domain.com:8000`.

If the above is not possible, is there a way to send requests with an IP from my VPC CIDR?

- NOTE - This is a private API Gateway with all VPC-E configured
  correctly.
- NOTE - As I am merely a simpleton, I do not have
  privileges to modify this proxy.
- NOTE - I'd rather not use lambda (if
  possible)

Answer (score 0):

Private endpoints are only private within the AWS ecosystem, they cannot be utilized outside them unless you establish connectivity between AWS VPC and your corporate network.

There are three ways to achieve this as far as i know

1. You can make your API Gateway be public and use WAF to control access to it. You can whitelist only your corporate proxy IP addresses that are only allowed to access this gateway.
2. Establish a VPN connection between your AWS VPC and the corporate network. This will allow you to use private endpoints without making them public using a secure encrypted pipe
3. Setup AWS Direct Connect between your AWS VPC and the corporate network. This may not be an option considering the cost to the value proposition

Comment: Im looking to integrate with a service that has whitelisted corporate IPs. The problem is that API Gateway assumes a Cloudfront IP (not my VPC CIDR) and hence it is being blocked.

Comment: AWS publishes a list of cloudfrontIPs for whitelisting purposes : http://d7uri8nf7uskq.cloudfront.net/tools/list-cloudfront-ips . The link source : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/LocationsOfEdgeServers.html

Comment: That won't work...not too secure since i would pretty much be whitelisting the world to my service. I do appreciate the link though...didn't realize they posted it!

Answer (score 0):

I just ended up using Lambda attached to my VPC w/ API Gateway proxy integration.